# SwiftUI delete core data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have written a delete all function in SwiftUI.  It compiles but fails when running on the simulator.

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "InvItem")

    // Create Batch Delete Request
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try context.execute(batchDeleteRequest)

    } catch {
        // Error Handling
        print("Did not clear core data")
    }
}
```

The error is as follows:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'InvItem''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `execute` the fetch request on the persistent store coordinator

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "InvItem")

    // Create Batch Delete Request
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    let persistentStoreCoordinator = context.persistentStoreCoordinator!
    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(batchDeleteRequest, with: context)

    } catch {
        // Error Handling
        print("Did not clear core data", error)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get this error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: @M.Thomas Have you initialised the the managedObjectContext environment value?

Comment: My code works if `context` is valid

Comment: How do I initialize it?  I am using the same statement in the main code above this function and it is working .  Sorry, I'm just a newbie.

Comment: `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` works only if in one of the view ancestors the managed object context is injected in `.environment(\.managedObjectContext,....`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did away with the function and moved the code to where the function was called and it worked!